# How to save two XML attributes of one childnode as one item in a List<>

Tags: c#, xml

I want to save two XML attributes of a child node combined in a List<> but they are saved individually and not somehow merged within the result.Add(). I would like to have the List with 30 entries, each entry should have currency and rate as items. Now there are 61 entries, one for each item. I want to convert that later to a JSON to pass on to a Service which stores that two values into a database.

[Screenshot of the List<>result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrTTL.png)

The XML I'm working with is https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml
The Childnodes are  and the Attributes are "currency" and "rate"

( I dont know how to do this with Linq expressions but there surely is a better way)

```
// This Method iterates through every Node if it has Attributes:

static void ecbXmlNanny(XmlNode ecbNode, List<ecbItems> result)
{
 // if Node has ChildNodes
 if (ecbNode != null && ecbNode.HasChildNodes)
 {
  foreach (XmlNode node in ecbNode.ChildNodes)
  {
   if (node.Attributes != null)
   {                       
    foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes)
    {
     listItems item = new listItems();

     // the needed Attributes are "currency" and "rate" 
     if (attribute.Name == "currency")
      {
       item.ecbCurrency = attribute.Value;
      }
      if (attribute.Name == "rate")
      {
       item.ecbRate = Decimal.Parse(attribute.Value);
      }
      result.Add(new listItems() { ecbCurrency = item.ecbCurrency, ecbRate = item.ecbRate });
     }
    }
    ecbXmlNanny(node, result);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: obviously you should create listItems outside attributes loop

Comment: you mean the result.Add() should be outside the foreach loop? i will try that.

Comment: Or just not using attribute loop and access them by name

Comment: now i have the List items combined as i wished from listentries 4 to 30, but the first 4 entries of the List are null and empty. weird. i declared  item.ecbCurrency = null; and                 item.ecbRate = 0; below the node.Attribute !=null and put the result.Add() at the end inside that scope

Comment: I tried to avoid using the Name because I dont know if that will be changed, obviously it is easier to just call them by the name

Comment: obviously not ... because you doesn't know where are you in a tree

Comment: i solved it by removing all null values from the list. thank you for the hint with having the result.Add outside the loop.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8gJ0.png

Comment: ah yes, that looks much better, I did not look into XPath, and I also forgot CultureInfo

Comment: You will not notice lack of CultureInfo untill you would ship your project to the coutry where dot is not a decimal separator :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works for me

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var results = doc.Elements()
       .Descendants()
       .Where(e => e.Attribute("currency") != null)
       .Select(e => new
       {
           currency = e.Attribute("currency").Value,
           rate = e.Attribute("rate").Value
       })
       .ToList();
```

result (in json format)

```
[
  {
    "currency": "USD",
    "rate": "1.0697"
  },
  {
    "currency": "JPY",
    "rate": "149.25"
  },
  {
    "currency": "BGN",
    "rate": "1.9558"
  },
  {
    "currency": "CZK",
    "rate": "23.687"
  },
  {
    "currency": "DKK",
    "rate": "7.4477"
  },
  {
    "currency": "GBP",
    "rate": "0.85823"
  },
  {
    "currency": "HUF",
    "rate": "370.42"
  },
  {
    "currency": "PLN",
    "rate": "4.5410"
  },
  {
    "currency": "RON",
    "rate": "4.9645"
  },
  {
    "currency": "SEK",
    "rate": "11.6455"
  },
  {
    "currency": "CHF",
    "rate": "0.9732"
  },
  {
    "currency": "ISK",
    "rate": "149.70"
  },
  {
    "currency": "NOK",
    "rate": "11.9670"
  },
  {
    "currency": "TRY",
    "rate": "22.2520"
  },
  {
    "currency": "AUD",
    "rate": "1.6407"
  },
  {
    "currency": "BRL",
    "rate": "5.4032"
  },
  {
    "currency": "CAD",
    "rate": "1.4514"
  },
  {
    "currency": "CNY",
    "rate": "7.6066"
  },
  {
    "currency": "HKD",
    "rate": "8.3786"
  },
  {
    "currency": "IDR",
    "rate": "15964.76"
  },
  {
    "currency": "ILS",
    "rate": "3.9970"
  },
  {
    "currency": "INR",
    "rate": "88.2070"
  },
  {
    "currency": "KRW",
    "rate": "1413.23"
  },
  {
    "currency": "MXN",
    "rate": "18.8695"
  },
  {
    "currency": "MYR",
    "rate": "4.9351"
  },
  {
    "currency": "NZD",
    "rate": "1.7775"
  },
  {
    "currency": "PHP",
    "rate": "60.057"
  },
  {
    "currency": "SGD",
    "rate": "1.4466"
  },
  {
    "currency": "THB",
    "rate": "37.204"
  },
  {
    "currency": "ZAR",
    "rate": "21.1567"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

this solved my issue, i put the result outside the inner Loop and removed all null or o items from the List:

```
        static void ecbXmlNanny(XmlNode ecbNode, List<ecbItems> result)
    {
        ecbItems item = new ecbItems();

        // if Node has ChildNodes
        if (ecbNode != null && ecbNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in ecbNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                // if ChildNode != empty
                if (node.Attributes != null)
                {
                    foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes)
                    {
                        // the needed Attributes are "currency" and "rate" 
                        if (attribute.Name == "currency")
                        {
                            item.ecbCurrency = attribute.Value;
                        }
                        if (attribute.Name == "rate")
                        {
                            item.ecbRate = Decimal.Parse(attribute.Value);
                        }
                        
                    }
                    result.Add(new ecbItems() { ecbCurrency = item.ecbCurrency, ecbRate = item.ecbRate });
                    
                }
                
                ecbXmlNanny(node, result);
            }
        }
        result.RemoveAll(item => item.ecbCurrency == null && item.ecbRate == 0);
    }
```